Is it possible to copy from native memory to a ByteBuffer using the new FFM API without producing temp objects?
We have an open-source project using sun.misc.Unsafe that we are migrating to the new Foreign Function & Memory (FFM) API. For our particular use-case (low-latency trading systems) it is important not to create any garbage (temp discarded instances) when receiving a message as these systems handle hundreds of thousands of messages per second.
We encountered an issue when copying from native memory straight into a direct ByteBuffer using the FFM API.
Using sun.misc.Unsafe, copying from memory to a ByteBuffer can be done without creating temporary objects and garbage collector overhead. However, with the FFM API, achieving the same does not seem currently possible without generating garbage via a call to MemorySegment.ofBuffer.
Is there a way to currently do that with FFM API that we are unaware of?
Below the current code we have with sun.misc.Unsafe, which does not produce any garbage, and the only way we are aware of doing it with the FFM API, which produces garbage.
// With sun.misc.Unsafe:
@Override
public void getByteBuffer(long address, ByteBuffer dst, int len) {
    if (!dst.isDirect()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("getByteBuffer can only take a direct byte buffer!");
    }
    try {
        long dstAddress = (long) addressField.get(dst); // get the memory address of this ByteBuffer
        dstAddress += dst.position(); // adjust the address for the ByteBuffer current position

        unsafe.copyMemory(address, dstAddress, len); // copy without temp objects

        dst.position(dst.position() + len); // adjust the ByteBuffer position to reflect the copy operation
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

// With FFM API:
@Override
public void getByteBuffer(long address, ByteBuffer dst, int len) {
    if (!dst.isDirect()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("getByteBuffer can only take a direct byte buffer!");
    }

    long offset = address - this.address; // offset in our 'segment'

    // Wrap the destination ByteBuffer in a temporary segment
    // This segment's data starts at dst.position()
    MemorySegment dstSegment = MemorySegment.ofBuffer(dst); // <====== temp object created here

    // Copy from 'segment' at 'offset' → dstSegment at offset 0 → length = 'len'
    dstSegment.copyFrom(this.segment, offset, 0, len);
    
    dst.position(dst.position() + len);
}


Note that with the sun.misc.Unsafe version we’re not really using the ByteBuffer itself but its underlying native memory address. Perhaps I’m overlooking something, but it seems that the FFM API should offer a way to copy data directly between native memory regions (the classic C memcpy)

If you do multiple copy operations to same ByteBuffer, and if appropriate for the app, you would be able to setup MemorySegment for re-use multiple times. eg with Arena.global()

@DuncG Thanks for your answer. I see what you are saying. It would be kind of cumbersome and slow as the ByteBuffer instances passed to the method can definitely change. It would require some kind of mapping from ByteBuffer to MemorySegment for reusing the same MemorySegment per ByteBuffer. This lookup in the critical path is far from ideal. I know the Panama Team has probably a lot on their plate but I will keep my fingers crossed that they will address that before discontinuing sun.misc.Unsafe. It is a show-stopper for low-latency systems.

Lookups in a map seem like overkill.  Refactor things so you're always keeping a ByteBuffer and its MemorySegment together, e.g. in whatever object actually holds the ByteBuffer.  This API went through many, many rounds of preview and feedback before it got finalized in Java 22, and is not likely to change.

A little more detail in the question may help, as "we’re not really using the ByteBuffer" doesn't match with "callers of this API/class are the ones that want to use a ByteBuffer", and "instances passed to the method can definitely change" means you are accepting that you will allocate objects for each ByteBuffer (yet are unhappy about MemorySegment). A MemorySegment can be derived from an address or allocated, and then used ".asByteBuffer()".

Hi @DuncG. I was trying to say that the sun.misc.Unsafe operation is simply copying from native memory location to native memory location. It does not know there is a ByteBuffer in that location. So as @QuânAnhMai answer below illustrates we would need a way to use FFM to copy between native memory locations. I'll probably going to have the same problem when I implement the other version of this method that receives a byte[] instead of a ByteBuffer as the destination.

Note that MemorySegment::ofBuffer does not take an Arena as an argument.

I think this should satisfy your requirements. The culprit is to create a constant MemorySegment that acts as the entirety of the memory, then you can operate on that segment as if you are working with raw memory:
// With FFM API:
static final MemorySegment EVERYTHING_SEGMENT = MemorySegment.NULL.reinterpret(Long.MAX_VALUE);

@Override
public void getByteBuffer(long address, ByteBuffer dst, int len) {
    if (!dst.isDirect()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("getByteBuffer can only take a direct byte buffer!");
    }

    long dstAddress = (long) addressField.get(dst) + dst.position();
    EVERYTHING_SEGMENT.copyFrom(this.segment, offset, dstAddress, len);
    dst.position(dst.position() + len);
}

Furthermore, if it is possible, I would suggest moving away from the ByteBuffer API, too.

Wow, thanks! I'll give it a try. Note that we’re not really using the ByteBuffer itself but its underlying native memory address. For byte arrays I'll probably do something similar. For a moment I thought that the FFM API did not want to allow copying raw memory regions like sun.misc.Unsafe does.

@JoasCoder I mean if you are not really using a ByteBuffer why bother with it and not just pass around raw addresses or wrap them in MemorySegment instances instead?

The callers of this API/class are the ones that want to use a ByteBuffer
